# How can I set label location in Pine Script so its on the line and not above or below it?

Tags: pine-script

I want the value to be placed on the line and not below bar.  How do I do that?  I only see abovebar and belowbar in pine-script manual.  Above and below is making my chart look very messy.

```
if isBullEngulf
bullEngulfOpen := line.new(bar_index - 1, open[1], bar_index, open[1], extend=extend.right, color=color.black)
bullEngulfLow := line.new(bar_index - 1, low < low[1] ? low : low[1], bar_index, low < low[1] ? low : low[1], extend=extend.right, color=color.green)
bullEngulfLowPrice = line.get_y1(bullEngulfLow)
offset                  =       input(15, maxval=900, title="Label Offset",step=5)
tl                      =       offset *(time - time[1])
bullEngulfLowLabel := label.new(x = t1 + time, y = na, text="\n"+tostring(bullEngulfLowPrice), style=label.style_none,size=size.normal,textcolor=color.white, yloc=yloc.belowbar)
//bullEngulfLowLabel := label.new(x = bar_index, y = na, text="\n"+tostring(bullEngulfLowPrice), style=label.style_none,size=size.normal,textcolor=color.white, yloc=yloc.belowbar)
bullEngulfHigh := line.new(bar_index - 1, high < high[1] ? high : high[1], bar_index, high < high[1] ? high : high[1], extend=extend.right, color=color.green)
bullEngulfHighPrice = line.get_y1(bullEngulfHigh)
bullEngulfHighLabel := label.new(bar_index - 1, high[1],text="\n"+tostring(high[1]),
 style=label.style_none,size=size.normal,textcolor=color.white, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can offset the X axis by calculating the time of each bar. Below code will shift the price label to right

```
offset                  =       input(15, maxval=900, title="Label Offset",step=5)
tl                      =       offset *(time - time[1])
bullEngulfLowLabel := label.new(x = tl + time, y = na, text="\n"+tostring(bullEngulfLowPrice), style=label.style_none,size=size.normal,textcolor=color.white, yloc=yloc.belowbar)
```

Comment: where do i put this code?  when i added it, i got this eerror Undeclared identifier 't1'?

Comment: replace the code you put in ur post with it. If you dont know how to do it, post all code and i ll do it.

Comment: i changed the code above, but I am getting this error now  line 52: Undeclared identifier 't1'

Comment: sorry, there was small typo error in code.. fixed.. please copy it again and apply it

Comment: thanks, now i get an error that says objects position using xloc.bar_index cannot be drawn further than 500 bars into the future.

Comment: please post full code or have a look at end of page, https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html

Comment: here is the full code.   https://pastebin.com/QZMYf9YY.    this site wouldn't let me post it, said it was too much code

Comment: done, you may want to change Y label coordinates 
https://pastebin.com/FRC63wnX

Comment: Thank you for your help.. I really appreciate it!  This is fixed.   Awesome job!

Comment: play with label offset. you have a problem with Y= na.. you need to change that. 
https://ibb.co/VJGYJFB
glad I helped.. off to bed, late here